# custom checkbox with hidden input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a custom checkbox so I can have both my own UI design, and still have the `input[type="checkbox"]` in the page for purpose of toggling css classes with it and being able to submit a form and it being taken into the form.

I am aware that if the input has `display: none;` it will not be passed into the form, so I will hide it since I actually don't use it visualy.

Question: what should I take into account when hidding it?

I'm thinking about giving it `position: absolute;` and then a negative margin so it will not show up. With the `label` tag I can still trigger it. But should I use opacity or visibility instead?

Comment: Someone posted a interesting answer but deleted it... And now I got a `-1` with no comment on why, or suggestion helping me improve the question if it needs so. Lets see what the future holds... I'm happy to receive feedback.

Comment: Don't know who voted down or why. I voted up since I find this question interesting and relevant to me as well.

Comment: I'm the one who deleted the answer, and the un-deleted it with a better edit.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, using `opacity:0;`, users will still be able to click it. click near the actual label on the snippet below:

```css
.chk { opacity:0; }
.chk + label {
    background-color:red;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.chk:checked + label { background-color:blue; }
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='mychk' class='chk' /><label for='mychk' ></label>
```

---

Now, using a negative `margin` will make the label disappear too:

```css
.chk { margin:-100px; }
.chk + label {
    background-color:red;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.chk:checked + label { background-color:blue; }
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='mychk' class='chk' /><label for='mychk' ></label>
```

---

Finally: `visibility:hidden` does the trick:

```css
.chk { visibility:hidden; }
.chk + label {
    background-color:red;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.chk:checked + label { background-color:blue; }
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='mychk' class='chk' /><label for='mychk' ></label>
```

### Conclusion:

use `visibility:hidden` to hide the `<input>`. This will make it invisible still with inline display in your page, without effecting the `label` using it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  height: 16px;      
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;      
}
 input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  content: "";
  height: 16px;
  left: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  width: 16px;
}
 input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #434452;  
  background:#434452;
}
label {
  color: #434452;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 100%;
  padding-left: 22px;
  cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='chk' class='chk' /><label for='chk' >check</label>
```